# Detect the Visual Studio build tools version at compile time

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, build-tools

Is there a way to get the build tools version being used by Visual Studio using a preprocessor flag or any other way such that the code/compiler can make compiler time decisions on how to compile the code?

There are some differences in the header files/code when using build tools v140 vs v143, however to keep it compatible with both versions of the build tools I would like to encapsulate some of the code using a `#ifdef` or something similar so it can build with either version without making any changes to the code and keep it backward compatible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can add the following to your Preprocessor Definitions:

`MSC_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_$(PlatformToolset);`

Then use it like so:

`#ifdef MSC_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_v140` or `#if defined ( MSC_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_v140 )`

For example:

```
#if defined ( MSC_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_v140 )
// Do something
#elif defined ( MSC_PLATFORM_TOOLSET_v143 ) // VS2022 Toolset
// Do something else
#endif
```

Comment: or use _MSC_VER or _MSC_FULL_VER

Comment: You want to watch out with those leading underscores though (they are used for "reserved identifiers"), especially when also using "_MSC" which is a prefix used by the compiler already.

Comment: @Christian.K, You're absolutely right, I've updated the answer.